# How to output via console in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, console

Good day to you. For some time now, I have been experiencing some issues when trying to run reactjs.

I don't know if the course I'm using is old and outdated, But I need your Help..

Take a look at the code Below and let me know if there's any error!

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
let count = 0;
const addOne = () => {
  console.log("Hello React");
}
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Let's Build Amazon Clone {count} </h1>
      <button onClick = {addOne}>+1</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I seriously don't know what's wrong with it. But you can lemme know.
Nothing is displaying in the console.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It works fine when I try it.

Comment: It looks fine to me. If you want to update your states in functional component. Then you have to use `hooks`. Here is the demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-fermi-5kf35?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Hi @yudhiesh,
Thanks for your reply. After much work, I noticed the error is coming from my end. I'm having issues with my NodeJs installed on my P.C
IS they a way I can completely Uninstall Node with it's components and modules?